# Change image using setAttribute javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am displaying photos in gallery from dropbox. Photos in gallery keep changing in 15 seconds. Issue is once I display a photo I unable to replace it by another photo after 15 secs.

I am posting snaps of my html and js code. I cant post full code because its big and confidential. I just want to know if there is anything I am doing wrong from syntax or js perspective or is there any other way to do it? I am using firefox browser.

html

```
<ul class="section">
    <li id="pic0" class='sub_section'
        data-path='data/5/images/01.jpg' //this is default image to be displayed
        data-title="Optional title"
        data-target='_blank' >
    </li>
    <li id="pic1" class='sub_section'
        data-path='data/5/images/10.jpg'
        data-title="Nullam aliquam"
        data-target='_blank' >
    </li>
</ul>
```

javascript

```
setInterval(setImages, 15000);
function setImages(urlArray) {//this is array which contains 2 image urls this is global variable)
    for(var i in urlArray){
        document.getElementById("pic"+i).removeAttribute("data-path",null);
        document.getElementById("pic"+i).setAttribute("data-path",urlArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: can u add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry..I dont know how to do that.

Comment: urlArray will always be empty in the code shown because setInterval doesn't pass anything.

Comment: So, you have argument in `setImages` definition. And how do you pass it to function call?

Comment: @codelearner: go to http://jsfiddle.net/, paste in your code, click "save" and then paste the new page url in your question/post.

Comment: I made this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/u378v75a/

the data-path is updated, but I don't know which API you're using to display image in your gallery.

Comment: I am passing urlArray from some other code and i have checked it contains urls and those 2 urls change after 15 seconds

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience I have posed snaps of my code html/js not full code.

Comment: urlArray is being set globally

Comment: I have updated question.  Added few lines in the end

Comment: hmm.. can you try putting an alert after u set the attribute?

Comment: Your code is 100% fine, there must be a problem with the other API your using that converts the data-path attr to an image etc. What are you using?

Comment: @Jonathan Anctil : I am using codecanyon api to diplay gallery

Comment: Just curious, you have tagged jQuery in the question, but you're not using it. Was that a mis-tag?

Comment: But first time it set my images correctly by replacing default images.

Comment: @jwatt1980:I can use jquery or javascript both if required

Comment: Could it be a problem related to image loading?

Comment: In jquery the loop can be replaced with `$.each(urlArray, function(i, el) { $('pic'+i).data("path", el); })` Don't know that it will fix anything, but that's why this is a comment.

Comment: @codelearner: Please provide an example of the contents of urlArray, preferably by adding code showing assigning the appropriate values to the array.

Comment: `for...in` is for iterating over object properties, don't use it to iterate over arrays. [It is a bad idea and causes lots of different problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea). Instead use a normal `for` statement or even better [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). In the future when ES6 is more widely supported you could also use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

Answer (score -1):

Yours looks like it only runs at first interval. Use this approach instead when doing setInterval.

```
var urlArray = [{src: 'http://riverboatsmusic.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/1shuu4q3.wizardchan.test_.png'},
                    {src: 'http://www.bealecorner.com/trv900/respat/eia1956-small.jpg'}];

    setInterval(function () {
        for(var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++){ 
            document.getElementById("pic"+i).setAttribute("data-path", urlArray[i].src);
            console.log("running");
        } 
    }, 3000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdb0efv1/1/

Comment: I have tried by putting alert its being called in 15 second interval, still I am trying with your solution

Comment: Check my jsfiddle code and put alert there. You updated the seconds there?

Comment: @codelearner btw, it won't be noticeable that the paths are changed except for the initial one. It's because the values are the same when changing them. It's like setting the same `Attribute` all over again.

Comment: may  I know why are you using src in url?

Comment: so it would get the `src` property on each values of the array. So at first loop it will get this value `http://riverboatsmusic.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/1shuu4q3.wizardchan.test_.png`